# ldap_group_search_base is not working as intented

Tags: ldap, openldap, ubuntu-20.04, sssd, rhel8

I've used the below-given sssd.conf file to authorize the users to a server. The issue is some users who are not listed under the **DN: cn=authorized,ou=rona,ou=servers,ou=groups,dc=yolo,dc=com** still can access it.
Users are created here **ou=users,dc=yolo,dc=com**. Any user listed here can access the resources as mentioned before.

server
**DN: ou=rona,ou=servers,ou=groups,dc=yolo,dc=com**

The configuration

```
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, autofs, sudo
domains = default

[nss]
homedir_substring = /home

[pam]

[domain/default]
id_provider = ldap
autofs_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
sudo_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap.yolo.com
ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://ldap.yolo.com
ldap_search_base = dc=yolo,dc=com
ldap_user_search_base = ou=users,dc=yolo,dc=com
ldap_group_search_base = ou=rona,ou=servers,ou=groups,dc=yolo,dc=com
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_tls_cacertdir = <path>/certs
cache_credentials = False
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
entry_cache_timeout = 6
ldap_network_timeout = 3
ldap_connection_expire_timeout = 6
debug_level = 9
ldap_default_bind_dn = uid=yolobind,ou=bind,dc=yolo,dc=com
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = PASSWORD
ldap_schema = rfc2307
ldap_use_tls = true
enumerate =  true

[sudo]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not filtering for that group, so every user is allowed.

You can add a filter like this:

```
ldap_access_filter = memberOf=cn=authorized,ou=rona,ou=servers,ou=groups,dc=yolo,dc=com
```

Check if `memberOf` matches your properties, could also be `uniqueMember`.

Comment: Tried that before with ```access_provider = ldap ```  it just removes access of every user. Is ```ldap_access_filter``` mandatory? if it used, is it possible to remove ```ldap_group_search_base```?

Comment: Why would you want to remove that? It's just the definition where sssd should look for groups.

Comment: I tried the solution you proposed, but it just removes access from every user. do you know the reason behind that behavior?

Comment: Did you check the membership attribute of the user objects for the correct name and value?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to log in with the admin user who is in the authorized group without the filter, when I applied it to remove the access from the unwanted users , all the other users's access including the admin get removed. In your opinion is this caused by sssd or the ldap ?

Comment: I can't tell you that, you are not providing enough information.

Comment: Checked the auth.log, getting this error ```"fatal: Access denied for user test-user by PAM account configuration [preauth]"```, when the ```ldap_access_filter``` is used.